# catkin_make in catkin_ws error

Tags: ros, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in using catkin, as a former rosbuild user. I was following the new tutorials online. After I learning how to build a package, on website:

BuildingPackages

After I modify the package.xml in the created package, and source the setup.bash in installation directory, the output of catkin_make is :

```
Base path: /home/wu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/wu/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/wu/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/wu/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/wu/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/wu/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4" in "/home/wu/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

and there is no build file of beginner_tutorials in the build/ directory.

However, on another website:
using_a_workspace

I tried another command

```
catkin_make --force-cmake
```

since I have compiled the workspace after I made the directory followed by the website:
InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

I am wondering is it correct to add --force-cmake after the catkin_make command or the problem occurs because some other issues?

Thanks
Kanzhi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51629/catkin_make-in-catkin_ws-error/) by [Kanzhi Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3892/kanzhi-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this was a bug in catkin_make:
https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/290
should be fixed with next release of catkin.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1